# Matplotlib on windows: interactive plots not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt4, backend

Attempting to get some very basic stuff working on my Windows 7 machine. If I run the below from the matplotlib documentation:

Script 1:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('qt4agg')  #Just using this to test backends
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ion()
plt.plot([1.6, 2.7])
```

Then I should get a line plotted and be able to change things via the terminal prompt. What actually happens is I get a blank figure and a spinning wheel, 'python.exe is not responding' and needs to be forced closed.

If I put:

Script 2:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('qt4agg')  #Just using this to test backends
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ioff()
plt.plot([1.6, 2.7])
plt.show()
```

Then I get the desired result but my terminal prompt is blocked from use.

The other thing is that the above are both run using the QT4Agg backend which is not what I want to use. Testing a couple of other backends (GTK3agg and Tkagg) I get the following results:

**GTK3Agg**

ION - Same error as when running with Qt4Agg, I get a blank figure and a spinning wheel, 'python.exe is not responding' and needs to be forced closed.

IOFF - Blank figure appears but no spinning wheel and I get 'python.exe has stopped working' immediately after the figure appears

**Tkagg**

ION - Blank figure appears but no spinning wheel and I get 'python.exe has stopped working' immediately after the figure appears

IOFF - Blank figure appears but no spinning wheel and I get 'python.exe has stopped working' immediately after the figure appears

I need to get it working with the other backends but as currently I can at least get the non-interactive one to work with qt4agg, getting the interactive one working with that seems like a good place to start. Any ideas?

Comment: I can't repro this on my Windows box - it works as expectd with interactive plots for Qt4agg and TKagg.  The "stopped working" implies a problem deeper than the python code.  Do you have a working `Qt` install for the code to bind to?

Comment: Hello, I'm running Anaconda so PyQt4 is bundled. The scripts run both run without issues in Spyder which uses Qt also I think?